# Galaxy S4 OpenCL examples/tutorials (SDK target: Linux)

Tags: android, linux, sdk, opencl, galaxy

The problem is that Adreno SDK with robust bunch of examples is available only for MSVS users. But I due to perfomance benefits have to apply **OpenCL development routine on Ubuntu** (currently x64 13.04) within Android SDK. And OpenCL Adreno documentation is too short for me for programming from scratch on non-target SDK OS (Linux instead of Windows).

Has anyone clear example or some kind of tutorial for OpenCL Galaxy S4 (with **Adreno 320** GPU) widget? Any futher help will be appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087440/android-opencl-image-processing-example-on-samsung for an example of running openCL on a Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does the Galaxy S4 actually come with OpenCL drivers? From what I [searched](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/mobile-technologies/mobile-gaming-graphics-optimization-adreno/26828), there are some missing libraries that are needed to load libOpenCL.so.

Could you please check with [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to see if you can open the library? If the return code of [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) is NULL, you can see the error message with [dlerror()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).

Could you also try to see if [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ee.cldevicetest) works? Or [this](https://bitbucket.org/codedivine/testcln10/src)?

Comment: Thank you for research. I will try dlopen() and second proposed OpenCL test widget new week after next one. Now I'm out of any available device. But I have to add that first one OpenCL test doesn't work with S4 because it's targeting only devices with Mali GPU (the Nexus 10).